# Use custom normalizer as default for all text/keywords fields in the elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to use case insensitive sorting in the elasticsearch. But ES uses ASCII sorting default. So to make case-insensitive searching. I have to use normalizer.

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "normalizer": {
      "custom_sort_normalizer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "char_filter": [],
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "asciifolding"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to apply this **custom_sort_normalizer** to all text or keyword based fields. As I am using AWS elasticsearch, I can not simply close the index and apply this normalizer. Either I have to reindex and create index from start, I want to avoid both this option for future.

Right now, I am adding manually in the mapping to tell elasticsearch use the normalizer. Is there anyway I can make it as default ?

Update : I am maintaining mapping using yaml file. Below is a sample mapping.

```
properties:
  studetName:
    type: text
    fields:
      keyword:
        type: keyword
        ignore_above: 256
  studentGender:
    type: text
    fields:
      keyword:
        type: keyword
        ignore_above: 256
  studentGroup:
    type: text
    fields:
      keyword:
        type: keyword
        normalizer: custom_sort_normalizer
        ignore_above: 256
```

My main objective is that every new text fields we add in this mapping.yaml (every new text/keyword file in that index) should by default use normalizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can utilize [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) to achieve what you want.
create your index template with mapping as follows:

```
 PUT my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "my_normalizer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [],
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I found the solution. But I didn't answer it.

Comment: From question- _I can not simply close the index and apply this normalizer. Either I have to reindex and create index from start, I want to avoid both this option for future._ @SagarRout Are you able to achive this? I am stuck with this. I have an index. I am trying to update the settings. I don't want to close the index or reindex.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have your custom `custom_sort_normalizer` applied to all the fields in your future elasticsearch indices. if yes, then you can simply use the [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html), which will allow you to define this setting in the template, and later on this template, you can apply to your future indices.

**From the docs**

> Index templates allow you to define templates that will automatically
> be applied when new indices are created. The templates include both
> settings and mappings and a simple pattern template that controls
> whether the template should be applied to the new index.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to use this ```custom_sort_normalizer``` for all text fields in the index as default. Right now I have to add everytime in the mapping or explicitly tell ES that to use this normalizer.

Comment: @SagarRout cool, than using template you can achieve it :)

Comment: That's great !! But I am not able to figure it out how to use index template's custom normalizer for text/keyword fields in the index. By chance, If you have anylink, Could you please share with me ? Anyways. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: But with index template's normalizer is not automatically applying on text fields.

Comment: i have added additional details of the index template in my answer, pls let me know if that helps @SagarRout